# Python telegram inline bot

Tags: python, inline, telebot

I was trying to write a bot that sends voice messages via inline. but selection handler is not working correctly.
Also how can I implement reading voice messages from local directory. thx

```
import telebot

bot_token = 'token'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)

@bot.inline_handler(lambda query: len(query.query) > 0)
def handle_inline_query(query):
    try:
        results = []
        
        result = telebot.types.InlineQueryResultVoice(
            id='1',
            voice_url='url',
            title='войс',
            voice_duration=10
        )
        results.append(result)
        
        bot.answer_inline_query(query.id, results)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


@bot.chosen_inline_handler(func=lambda chosen_inline_result: True)
def send_voice_message(chosen_inline_result):
    try:
        print('jjh')
        if chosen_inline_result.result_id == '1':
            voice_url = 'url'
            bot.send_voice(chosen_inline_result.from_user.id, voice_url)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

bot.polling()
```